# Is thread safe to assign a shared_ptr nullptr?

Tags: c++11, thread-safety, shared-ptr

Suppose there is a shared_ptr:

```
std::shared_ptr<MyClass> myPtr = std::make_shared(new MyClass());
```

In worker thread:

```
myPtr = nullptr;
```

In main thread:

```
if( myPtr != nullptr )
{
    // do something
}
```

Is the code above thread safe? Or can the main thread see the new value immediately?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not thread-safe.

A `shared_ptr` behaves like a built-in type regarding thread-safety: Concurrent access to distinct objects is fine, while concurrent access to the *same* object is not. That is, multiple threads may manipulate different `shared_ptr`s pointing to the same object as they like. But as soon as you share the `shared_ptr` itself, things get dangerous.

Use the [atomic non-member functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic) to access the same `shared_ptr` object concurrently from multiple threads:

```
// atomically set myPtr to nullptr
std::atomic_store(&myPtr, std::shared_ptr<MyClass>{});
[...]


// atomically check the current value of myPtr
if(std::atomic_load(&myPtr) != nullptr) [...]
```

Note that this only works if *all* threads accessing the `shared_ptr` only do so through the atomic functions. Otherwise you might still end up with a data race.
To make this restriction more explicit in the source code, C++20 introduced specializations for [`std::atomic<std::shared_ptr>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) and deprecated the old free functions.

Comment: std::atomic_store(&myPtr, nullptr); can not compiled for gcc 7.5.0